# how to search in Mongodb by querying multiple fields in the same document

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, nosql

I'm going over a project I've taken over which is crashing in this [doctrine/mongoDB](https://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) query:

```
/**
 * Deactivate all Device documents via set 'activate = false' and unsetting 
 * passenger field for all devices that has passenger = $oPassenger 
 * and Device._id != oDevice
 * @param Document\Device $oDevice
 * @param Document\Passenger $oPassenger
 */
public function deactivateDuplicateDevices(Document\Device $oDevice,
                                           Document\Passenger $oPassenger)
{
    $passengerId = new \MongoId($oPassenger->getId());
    $deviceId = new \MongoId($oDevice->getId());

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('Device')
        ->update()
        ->multiple(true)
        ->field('activated')->set(false)
        ->field('passenger')->unsetField()->equals($passengerId)
        ->field('_id')->notEqual($deviceId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
}
```

it seems to me that the author is running multiple queries on the same document ie
find all documents where

- passenger == passengerId AND
- device != deviceId

I'm trying to recreate this query piece by piece  (in JSON and running it on the mongo console) to see where the problem is. this is the final input I got (to the mongo initiated, this may seem absurd.. but please bear with me):

```
db.Device.update(
    {
        passenger:{
                    $ne: "538c6eac3c0ab224080041aa"
                  }
    },
    {
        _id:{
                $ne: "538eb8d205dafff40a0041ad"
            } 
    }
    {
        $unset:{ 
                    passenger:""
                }
    },
    {
        $set:
                {
                    activated:false
                }
    }               
)
```

I wanted to test the first part, namely the multiple queries (obviously searching for passenger alone and _id alone work.. but when i combine them):

```
db.Device.find({
                    _id:{
                            $ne:ObjectId("538eb8d205dafff40a0041ad")
                        }
                }, 
                {
                    passenger:{
                            $ne:"538c6eac3c0ab224080041aa"
                        }
                } 
)
```

I get this error:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: passenger: { $ne: \"538c6eac3c0ab224080041aa\" }",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$and` (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)

```
db.Device.find({ $and: [ {
                _id:{
                        $ne:ObjectId("538eb8d205dafff40a0041ad")
                    }
            }, 
            {
                passenger:{
                        $ne:"538c6eac3c0ab224080041aa"
                    }
            } ] }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do

```
db.Device.find({
                    _id: {$ne: ObjectId("538eb8d205dafff40a0041ad")},
                    passenger: {$ne: "538c6eac3c0ab224080041aa"}
               })
```

or

```
db.Device.update({
                      _id: {$ne: ObjectId("538eb8d205dafff40a0041ad")},
                      passenger: {$ne: "538c6eac3c0ab224080041aa"}
                 },
                 {
                     $unset: {passenger: 1},
                     $set: {activated: false}
                 })
```

Note that there is only one query object argument and one update object argument. There are other optional arguments you can check out in the docs.